# iOS 7 cancelAllLocalNotifications issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

In iOS 7 when I use the method `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];` I have a very strange behavior: when I receive a new notification (I stay in home screen and look at the app icon) the app's icon show the badge and after a few milliseconds the badge disappear. If I remove this line of code the badge remains.

Answer (score 0):

That's a method  `cancelLocalNotification:`  not   `cancelAllLocalNotifications`

Try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:<#(UILocalNotification *)#>];
```

Comment: This is not what I'am looking for. I haven't a single notification. When the app is open I want remove all notification from notification center, instead user cancel manually later.